# SharePoint 2010 Reporting Services Integration Set Server Defaults Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

We are using one FrontEnd server and one DataBase server on our current farm with reporting services integration. We need to change your farm to on FrontEnd server, one Application server and one DataBase server. I configured reporting services integration using Central Administration-->General Application Settings-->Reporting Services Integration. But when I ran reports, I'm getting this error

```
The HTTP service located at xxxxx:32843/12c5963195d84f1d8fcadca21d0f9d32/ReportingWebService.svc is too busy. 
The HTTP service located at xxxxx:32843/12c5963195d84f1d8fcadca21d0f9d32/ReportingWebService.svc is too busy. 
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

Also, ULS logs give me this:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

When I try to Set Server Defaults option in Central Administration I'm getting this:

[image]

I'm not getting this error on our production server, but only on our FrontEnd and Application test servers. How can I solve this?  What I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my poblem with following cmdlets.

```
$sts = Get-SPRSServiceApplication
$sts.Provision()
```